# Fix fabricjs Animating Demo

Tags: fabricjs

I'm new in fabricjs. I'm expecting to draw a line with a circle moving on it.

I found this [Demo](http://fabricjs.com/cross) quite useful, but I have no idea why the crosses are not animating. I think that they are supposed to change their size.

So can anyone tell me how to fix this demo? Or is there anything I've done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: there are some error in the demo

Comment: @Inferon But what exactly the error is? I really need it in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fabricjs 1.7.0 introduced [object caching](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching).  It would appear that in the animation demo the crosses are being redrawn from the cache, so they don't update.  For a quick and dirty solution, if you disable caching (by setting `objectCaching` to false) at an object level, the demo works again.  Alternatively, you can set the `dirty` flag on each object to let it know that the object has changed.  For example, in the timeout from the demo, just modify it slightly:

```
canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
    obj.animateWidthHeight();
    obj.dirty = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7gvJG/139/

Comment: Thank you very much, Ben. It really helps me a lot.